# Reload div with JQuery/Ajax when a database table colum updates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am looking for a way to check if the database column value has recently changed and have jquery/ajax load a certain page into a specific div container.

Example, Lets say if I the main page, I have 1.php displayed in div with the id status.

on another page I press a button or click a url that updates a column in a database.

Database table name is Status

### userID  |  Allow_bets

```
   1     |   No
```

Again the button or Url changes the Allow_bets column to yes

How would I pass get jquery/Ajax that a change in the database was made and get it to load a new page 2.php in the same div container?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get Javascript to 'listen' for database changes in the way you describe.

The best solution I can think of would be to use setInterval to retrieve the information from the database every 10 seconds (or whatever frequency you require).